# How can I get my code to wait for me to scan my second RFID?

Tags: c++, rfid

Is there a way for me to pause my code in the middle of the two if statements so I can scan the second RFID so the code can continue on to the second if statement with the information from the second RFID?

```
void loop()
{
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {

    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor

  Serial.print("UID tag :");
  String content= "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {


     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));

  }
  Serial.println();
  //Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  int count = 0;

  if (content.substring(1) == "89 E7 75 47") 
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized access"); 
    Serial.println();
    digitalWrite(yellowLED, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(yellowLED, LOW);

  count = count + 1;
  }
 else   {
    Serial.println(" Access denied");
    Serial.println();
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);


if (content.substring(2) == "F9 9A 76 47")
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized access"); 
    Serial.println();
    digitalWrite(yellowLED, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(yellowLED, LOW); 
    count = count + 1;
  }
 else   {
    Serial.println(" Access denied");
    Serial.println();
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  }

if (count == 2 ) {
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);

}

}
}
```

I want to scan two RFIDs within the duration of the code but the whole code runs through after I've scanned one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait until data is available, you can use `Serial.available()`. It is a handy function that returns a `bool`:

```
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
{
  return;
}

while(! Serial.available()){}

// Select one of the cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {

  return;
}
```

Keep in mind that the serial buffer should be either read completely before the next loop, or `Serial.flush()` should be called.

Comment: I added `Serial.flush();
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
{
  return;
}

while(! Serial.available()){}

// Select one of the cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {

  return;
}` in the middle of my two if statements but every time I scan my second RFID it says access denied. Is there anything else I can do? or is there a mistake in my code?

Comment: I placed the `Serial` statements based on where I understand you want them. Are they in the correct place?

Comment: Also, are you sure about the codes? If I recall correctly, RFID codes you are checking are ASCII codes. You may have to convert them to characters.